# Why do the dual spaces of a countable Hilbert space form an increasing chain?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, distribution-theory, dual-spaces

Let $H$ be a vector space and $\{(\cdot, \cdot)_n\}$ a countable increasing set of inner products on $H$, i.e.
$$(\phi, \phi)_1 \leq (\phi, \phi)_2 \leq \ldots, \quad \phi \in H$$
that are compatiable in the sense that if $\{\phi_i\} \in H$ and $\phi_i \rightarrow 0$ with respect to $\|\cdot \|_m$, then if $\{\phi_i\}$ is cauchy in $\|\cdot \|_n$ we also have that $\phi_i \rightarrow 0$ with respect to $\|\cdot \|_n$.

Define $H_n$ to be the completion of $H$ with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_n$ induced by the inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)_n$. Then $H$ is said to be countably Hilbert if it is complete relative to the topology generated by the neighborhood basis about $0 \in H$ given by:
$$U_{n, \epsilon} = \{\phi \in H: \|\phi\|_n < \epsilon\}$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon > 0$. It is easy to see that with this topology $H = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty H_n$.

Now let $H_n'$ be the dual space of $H_n$. In volume 4 of Gelfand's book *Generalized Functions* he says:

> ...let $F$ be an element of the space $H_n'$. Then obviously $F$ is continuous relative to the topology on $H$, i.e. $F$ is an element of $H'$. From this it follows that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty H'_n \subset H'$. On the other hand, if $F$ is a linear functional on $H$, then as was mentioned in Section 1.2, $F$ is continuous relative to some of the norms, say $\|\phi\|_n = \sqrt{(\phi, \phi)_n}$, i.e. it belongs to the space $H'_n$. Thus $H' = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty H'_n$. We note that the spaces $H_n'$ form an increasing chain $$H_1' \subset H_2' \subset \ldots.$$ In fact, since $(\phi, \phi)_m \leq (\phi, \phi)_n$ for $m \leq n$, then from the boundedness of a functional $F$ in the ball $(\phi, \phi)_m \leq 1 $ follows its boundedness in the ball $(\phi, \phi)_n \leq 1$, i.e. if $F$ belongs to $H_m'$ then it belongs to $H_n'$.

How does $F$ being continuous relative to the topology of $H$ imply that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty H'_n \subset H'$? How does Gelfand uses boundedness of $F$ to obtain the sequence of dual spaces above? Is there any intuitive way to see what's going on here?

Comment: $F$ is an arbitrary element of $H_n’$. Then it was proved that it is continuous with respect to the topology on $H$, so $F \in H’$. That means $H_n’ \subseteq H’$, no?

Comment: When the norm gets stronger, it becomes easier for a linear functional to be bounded. (This can be seen by a direct argument or just noting that a stronger norm means more open sets.) That’s really all that increasing sequence of dual spaces is all about.

Comment: @DavidGao Oh yes I see now, thank you. As a follow up, how does $H$ being an element of $H_n'$ imply that $F$ is also continuous as an element of $H'$? For the second point, how does a stronger norm imply more open sets?

Comment: The topology on $H$ is generated by all norms $||\cdot||_n$, i.e., open sets on $H$ are generated by subsets of $H$ which are open under $||\cdot||_n$ for some $n$. In particularly, this means if a functional is continuous w.r.t. $||\cdot||_n$, then it is continuous w.r.t. the topology on $H$.

Comment: If $||\cdot||_m \geq ||\cdot||_n$, then any set $O$ open under $||\cdot||_n$ must also be open under $||\cdot||_m$. This is because, as $O$ is open under $||\cdot||_n$, for any $x \in O$ there is a $||\cdot||_n$-open ball $B_n(x, \epsilon)$ around $x$ contained in $O$, but as $||\cdot||_m \geq ||\cdot||_n$, $B_m(x, \epsilon) \subseteq B_n(x, \epsilon) \subseteq O$, i.e., for any $x \in O$ there is an $||\cdot||_m$-open ball around $x$ contained in $O$, so $O$ is open under $||\cdot||_m$ as well. This shows that there are at least as many open sets under $||\cdot||_m$ as under $||\cdot||_n$.

Comment: The two norms could generate the same collection of open sets. That happens iff the norms are equivalent (this is one of the definitions of equivalence of norms). If they are not equivalent, then, $||\cdot||_m$ must generate strictly more open sets than $||\cdot||_n$.

Comment: As a side note, I should point out here that your statement “then $H$ is said to be countably Hilbert if it is complete relative to the topology …” is a bit strange. There’s no notion of some space being complete w.r.t. a topology. Instead, it should have been it is complete w.r.t. the uniform structure generated by these norms.

Comment: @DavidGao Thank you very much! There is just one small detail I did not fully understand. How does $||\cdot||_m \geq ||\cdot||_n$ imply that  $B_m(x, \epsilon) \subseteq B_n(x, \epsilon)$?

Comment: Let $y \in B_m(x, \epsilon)$. Then $||y - x||_m < \epsilon$. Thus, $||y - x||_n \leq ||y - x||_m < \epsilon$, i.e., $y \in B_n(x, \epsilon)$.

Comment: @DavidGao That was a lot simpler than I thought, thank you for all your help!